# dlopen and dlclose memory management in C appln

Tags: c, memory-management, dll, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I use dlopen to load a dynamic library say "lib1.so" and call one exposed function say A1,
A1 function allocate a dynamic memory of 100kb using malloc but not deallocate that, in the main function again I all dlclose.  [dlopen, call function A1 , dlclose]

I repeate the step say 10 times, Purify report this as memory leak of 1000KB
, valgrind reports Indirectly lost 1000KB.

Could you please suggest 100 KB * 10 times = 1000KB , Is a real memory leak?
As I have called dlclose, so all memory allocated for dynamic libs are automaticaly freed 
when we call dlclose?

OS: Linux
Programming lan : C

Comment: Without seeing any code, I guess that you should only call dlopen one time for each library.  This maps the library into process memory space for the life of the process.

Comment: That's correct, But I need to know the behaviour , There may be a chance that applciation can call dlopen / dlclose many times...

Comment: You've essentially answered your own question - the behavior is that you call dlopen once per library or get memory leaks. The only exception I know of is the case (used it in Solaris) of calling exec with and with an earlier fcntl() call on the the file handle for dlopen (handle == a file descriptor) with FC_CLOEXEC set. After the call the child process no longer has an open handle. There is no need to call dlopen repeatedly. Period.  Do you know about dlsym() to get entry points for functions - that you can call over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

`dlclose` doesn't free memory allocated with `malloc`. It only frees the static variables declared in the library. You should explicitly free any allocated memory in your library, possibly in the `_fini` function.

Answer (score 3):

The man page for dlclose doesn't say anything about freeing memory when it's called.

```
dlclose()
   The  function  dlclose()  decrements the reference count on the dynamic
   library handle handle.  If the reference count drops  to  zero  and  no
   other  loaded  libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is
   unloaded.

   The function dlclose() returns 0 on success, and nonzero on error.
```

No magic.

If you're using linux you could try [this method](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) to wrap malloc() and keep track of the allocated memory.

Comment: My scenario is calling dlopen and dlclose in a loop

Comment: Still no magic. I guess you don't have control over lib1.so? If they haven't linked their own version of malloc() your option could be to wrap malloc() in lib1.so to a version with garbage collection, or manage a list with the allocated memory that you free on exit.

Answer (score 2):

No, memory is reclaimed when the process terminates, not when dynamic libraries are closed.

Comment: You can't be sure about that either, it depends on the OS.

Comment: @onemasse Well it's a UNIX-based O/S as he's using `dlopen()` et al, so I can be sure.